# Relative positioning, div stacking issue in ie 7

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index

This is my example code which is not working as expected in IE7  - I think position:relative; is the issue for IE7

```
.oner {
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  background:#fff;
  border:5px solid #e4e4e4;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:20px;
}

.onea {
  position:absolute;
  height:500px;
  right:0;
  width:200px;
  background: #eee; 
  z-index:999;
}

.onet {
  position:absolute;
  height:500px;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  background:red; 
  z-index:999;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height:500px;width:900px;margin:auto;">
    <div class="oner">
        <div class="onea">IE IE7 this div goes behind the "oner" div below </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oner">
        <div class="onet">My name is Sumit Kumar Ray my email is ..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What happens is that the `onea` div goes behind the following `oner` div, but in other browsers it overlays it

Comment: Can you please tell us what the actual problem is? Seems a little difficult to decipher...

Comment: Please tidy this up - clarify exactly what you want to know, re-format your code example so it's readable, and tell us what you've tried to mitigate the problem.

Comment: Please give us the html part too, where the styles are applied, and a screenshot would also be helpful (for those of us who don't have ie7)

Comment: I think this belongs on doctype.com.

Comment: @sumit, I've tried to clarify the question as per what I saw in IE7 - if it's not right do feel free to re-edit and add in an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting a `z-index` on a div is actually supposed to create a stacking context, not simply bring the div, it's applied to, above another.. so while I do think IE7 didn't get it quite right, (surprise!)

I think it would be better to make the `oner` divs the ones that create the start of the stack by setting the `z-index` on them, and what you want it for the first `oner` to have a higher `z-index` than the second

```
<div style="height:500px;width:900px;margin:auto;">
    <div class="oner" style="z-index: 1;">
        <div class="onea">IE IE7 this div goes behind the "oner" div below </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oner">
        <div class="onet">My name is Sumit Kumar Ray my email is ..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this there is no need for the Absolutely Positioned children to have a z-index at all, as those divs now take their "z level" from their relatively positioned parent - IE and the stack can be quite confusing!

CSS:

```
.oner {
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  background:#fff;
  border:5px solid #e4e4e4;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:20px;
}

.onea {
  position:absolute;
  height:500px;
  right:0;
  width:200px;
  background: #eee; 
}

.onet {
  position:absolute;
  height:500px;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  background:red; 
}
```

However it does mean that if you have more than two as in this example you need to set the levels on all the `oner` divs with the first one being the highest.. (that's why I put the `oner` style inline in the HTML if you have more you might need some more classes to separate them)

Comment: Its not issue because of z-index its issue because of position relative.

Comment: yes but you need position relative to get the absolute divs to take their position from don't you? Do you want that div on the right side to go over the top? - if so it's a stacking context, (z-index) issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since both the inner divs have a zindex of 999 the second should overlay the first, although zindex results can be unpredictable across browsers. Really you should set different zindex values to accurately control depth.

Comment: that the not issue I have tried to do the same but problem is the relative thing.